# Amazon CloudSearch Gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-cloudsearch

Is there a gem other than:

- https://github.com/wellbredgrapefruit/asari
- https://github.com/spokesoftware/aws_cloud_search

for using aws cloud search in ruby? I'm trying to evaluate which one to use and want to make sure I'm not missing the_gem_one_that_everyone_uses.

Comment: asari seems to be more actively maintained

Comment: Agreed; both AWSCloudSearch and Cloudsearchable seem to only support the 2012 API [1](https://github.com/awslabs/cloudsearchable/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=API_VERSION),[2](https://github.com/spokesoftware/aws_cloud_search/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AWSCloudSearch%3A%3AAPI_VERSION&type=Code). That's unfortunate as these gems seem to be well written, but hopefully we can coalesce all the needed functionality into Asari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also Cloudsearchable: https://github.com/awslabs/cloudsearchable

It provides AR-like query building syntax and a simple API for mapping ActiveModel-like objects to a Cloudsearch index.